DLL load failed while importing _imaging: current solutions do not work
I have a similar problem as others and followed the suggested answers, without success.
Everything was working fine until I did a conda update -c conda-forge --all
As a result, in Windows 11 with spyder IDE 5.5.4, I got conda 24.5.0, python 3.9.13 or .16, matplotlib-base 3.8.4, matplotlib-inline 0.1.7, pillow 9.4.0 as it seems to be the cause.
I reinstalled matplotlib.
I upgraded pillow again and then forced its reinstallation. Then I downgraded it to version 9.3.0 as suggested.
I then did conda install python=3.8.0 as suggested but also it seemed to be OK, the version I can read on spyder is still 3.9.16.
I'm not an expert and do not really care about any last version as long as it works. Current error message is :
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\didie\.spyder-py3\python_from_vba.py:121
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:161
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:27
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:52
    from PIL import Image

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:100
    from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

What kind of easy trick could I do to have my system running again (feel free to be detailed please)?

I found this comment "this issue is coming back now in the most recent version, to help anyone struggling with deployment issues, a stable version on Windows seems to be v9.0.0 – Conor Aug 1, 2022 at 20:00" in this post ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. when trying to "from PIL import Image"
So, instead of pillow version 9.3.0 of pillow, I installed version 9.0.0 with Python 3.9.16 and it works.
If it helps others...
